# Loading a value from an array without its address

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have this code:

```
int arr[] = { 299, 3190, 4892, 256};
 __asm
{
    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR[arr] // EAX will be our number.
    MOV EAX, [EAX]          // Setting EAX to where it's pointing.
}
```

I need EAX to be the first number in the array, but I don't want this to be in 2 lines of code (obviously if there's another way, it'll be better.)
I'm no amateur in ASM, but I forgot it mostly, and I need some refreshments. Is there a way to do this in a single line of code? Thanks!

EDIT:
The compiler is MASM x86, the one given in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, but no idea how to do that in inline asm. Also you forgot to mention what compiler you use, but looks like microsoft. PS: did you find the "edit" link yet? :)

Comment: @Jester Oh yes, thanks! =)
And I changed the question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your second line of assembly code :

```
int arr[] = { 299, 3190, 4892, 256};
 __asm
{
    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR[arr] // ◄■■■ HERE EAX GETS THE FIRST ARRAY VALUE.
    MOV EAX, [EAX]          // ◄■■■ UNNECESSARY!
}
```

When you move `DWORD PTR[arr]` into `EAX`, you are actually moving the first value of the array into `EAX`. You don't need the address because `arr` already points to its first value.

Comment: On debug, when I remove the second line, it shows:
EAX 2686352 unsigned int.

However with the second line:
EAX 299 unsigned int.

2686352 is the *address* of the value.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't show that for me. Are you using Visual Studio 2015?
Mine does show the ADDR, and not the value contained in it

Comment: @NoamRodrik, try to simplify the line : `MOV EAX, arr`. That's all you need.

Comment: Oh, I've been writing it wrong. It works!
Question though, how to make it work on:
int* pArr = arr;
without the second line?

Comment: @NoamRodrik, I don't think you can, because in this case you have a pointer to another memory location.